# Error: library not found for -lsrt.1.5.2 (SRT Library)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, protocols

I'm facing an issue while building **Secure Reliable Transport (SRT)** library using Xcode.

Here is the library link: [Secure Reliable Transport (SRT)](https://github.com/Haivision/srt) Protoaol

I have followed all necessary setups to compile library

**Log**

```
Ld /Users/mac-0008/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SRT_Lib_Build-atkwslgovxzmrvaqlhfwgtiinzsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SRT_Lib_Build.app/SRT_Lib_Build normal (in target 'SRT_Lib_Build' from project 'SRT_Lib_Build')
    cd /Users/mac-0008/Desktop/Renis/Demos/XCODE-DEMOS/SRT_Lib_Build
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -target arm64-apple-ios15.4 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS15.4.sdk -L/Users/mac-0008/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SRT_Lib_Build-atkwslgovxzmrvaqlhfwgtiinzsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/mac-0008/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SRT_Lib_Build-atkwslgovxzmrvaqlhfwgtiinzsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/mac-0008/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SRT_Lib_Build-atkwslgovxzmrvaqlhfwgtiinzsx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SRT_Lib_Build.build/Debug-iphoneos/SRT_Lib_Build.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SRT_Lib_Build.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/mac-0008/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SRT_Lib_Build-atkwslgovxzmrvaqlhfwgtiinzsx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SRT_Lib_Build.build/Debug-iphoneos/SRT_Lib_Build.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SRT_Lib_Build_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fembed-bitcode-marker -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -L/usr/lib/swift -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/mac-0008/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SRT_Lib_Build-atkwslgovxzmrvaqlhfwgtiinzsx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SRT_Lib_Build.build/Debug-iphoneos/SRT_Lib_Build.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SRT_Lib_Build.swiftmodule -lsrt.1.5.2 -framework Pods_SRT_Lib_Build -Xlinker -no_adhoc_codesign -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/mac-0008/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SRT_Lib_Build-atkwslgovxzmrvaqlhfwgtiinzsx/Build/Intermediates.noindex/SRT_Lib_Build.build/Debug-iphoneos/SRT_Lib_Build.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SRT_Lib_Build_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/mac-0008/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SRT_Lib_Build-atkwslgovxzmrvaqlhfwgtiinzsx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/SRT_Lib_Build.app/SRT_Lib_Build

ld: library not found for -lsrt.1.5.2
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Please share your solution.
Thank you!

Comment: Assume you are following https://github.com/Haivision/srt/blob/master/docs/build/build-iOS.md?

Comment: Already followed setp's and generated all files, also added .dylib file to Xcode project and try to build it

Comment: Have you come up at any solution?